# How to get Layer size (Width and Height)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have a number of layers in a Photoshop document.

I want to find out what a specific layer's width and height is. How do I do that?

Comment: My god how embarrassing it is for Adobe that people actually have to ask these basic things about Photoshop. And even more embarrassing that as a professional user of many other tools (even from Adobe) I and 63000 others have to search for it online. Adobe isn't friends with usability apparently.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Option 1.**

I have an action that does this:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

When I run this action I'm left with `New document window`. The `width` and `height` in the window are the clipboard image dimensions = your objects/layers dimensions.

You then can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the window.

( On windows just think of the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> )

---

**Option 2.**

You can make a selection of the layer for example by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd> clicking the layer thumbnail and then looking at the `info panel` <kbd>F8</kbd>, it will show you the dimensions of the selection.

[image]

From the upper right corner where you can see the arrow pointing down, you can find the options and within there you can set the `ruler unit` to pixels or what ever you want it to show.

---

**Option 3.**

Use `Free transform` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and when free transform is active, go check the `Info panel` <kbd>F8</kbd> as shown above. This works even if the object is outside the document area.

---

Here's another answer that is slightly related:
[How to measure the distances in .psd](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38005/how-to-measure-the-distances-in-psd/38037#38037)

Especially the bottom part of the answer that lists methods to exporting layer styles as css, which includes width and height, of course.

Comment: I tried all your method, but seems that all of them could only give out **document dimension** (canvas size?), not dimension of a particular layer (I had that particular layer selected)

Comment: @Philip007 Are you sure your layer is not the same size as your document?

Comment: Now I understand what's happening: the "naughty" layer is a smart object before I tried check its dimension. With layers not being turned into smart object, your methods totally work

Comment: @Philip007 Well, I'm not sure I understand what is happening. Smart object should be just as easy to measure with these methods as a raster layer. Sometimes a smart object might even be better. For example: If you have layer style Drop shadow applied to your layer, the shadow won't be included to the dimensions. If however you use smart object or rasterize the layer style, then you'll be able to measure the layer with the shadow included.

Comment: Thanks for the drop shadow tip:) As for dimension, assume the layer is a smart object, `cmd-T` and `cmd-click` layer thumbnail will show different width and height in Info panel, provided that `canvas size` and `smart object size` are indeed different. I can't remember which shows what though, you can have a try

Comment: @Philip007 Didn't you say before that all of those methods gave you document dimensions? Now you said that they aren't all the same...? :) It's very difficult to guess blindly.

Comment: Option #3 seems by far the fastest when trying to check width of multiple things to reproduce on HTML. To change the ruler unit at will, right-click the ruler (before using `transform`) and a menu with all options will be presented.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work. `Info panel` doesn't show `width` and `height`.

Comment: @Green The only thing I can think of is that you don't have anything selected. Which could mean that the layer you tried to take a selection from, actually doesn't have anything in it... or it somehow failed. What if you just take Rectangular marquee tool and make a random selection? Does it then show the size of that selection in the info panel?

Comment: @green Make sure you `Cmd` click on the layer *thumbnail* not the layer name.

Comment: Joonas: gentleman, scholar, artist.

Comment: @Joonas, the lifesaver.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who wants to grab width/height in a single click and copy it, I created a script (based on [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21162/photoshop-action-to-determine-dimensions-of-layer)). You can bind the script to a hotkey too, as described below.

---

**Step 1: Save the script**

Copy the code below and save it in a file named "getLayerSize.jsx". If using Notepad, save the file WITH the double quotes.

```
function getLayerSizeToCopy(){
    var layer = activeDocument.activeLayer; //Grab the currently selected layer

    // Calculate length and width based on the rectangular bounds of the selected layer
    var length = layer.bounds[2]-layer.bounds[0]; //Grab the length
    var width = layer.bounds[3]-layer.bounds[1]; //Grab the width

    // Remove pixels from the length/width "200 px" => "200"
    length = length.toString().replace(' px', '');
    width = width.toString().replace(' px', '');

    prompt( "Layer Size: ", length + ", " + width );
}
getLayerSizeToCopy();
```

---

**Step 2: Create an Action**

Open the action menu if not already (Window > Actions). Create a group if you prefer. Add a new action, you can set an F-key here.

[image: binding the action "Get Layer Size" to the key "F6"]

---

**Step 3: Record a macro that runs the script**

Click "Record" to start recording events for the macro. Then run the script from File > Scripts > Browse. Once you run it, close the popup with width/height. Now stop recording.

---

**Finished!**

Test the macro by pressing the hotkey assigned, or run the macro manually. Hopefully it works!

[image: Layer size of a polygon is displayed in a popup]

Note: Photoshop may lag if you select a large number of layers or a large group, instead of a single layer. I don't know how to fix that, but just wait for a few moments and it should catch up.

---

Troubleshooting:

If you get a script error, check that a layer is selected and not a group or adjustment layer.

If you can't see the script for step 3, make sure the filetype is ".jsx". Windows might name it ".jsx.txt" which will count as a text file, and you won't see it.