# How can any color width and height be found in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

How do we get the width and height of any color in Illustrator in a document. With PHOTOSHOP we know this when we select it in the Ctrl+ Color Palette in the channel, but how can we find it with ILLUSTRATOR. Can a script do this?

Comment: *Colors* don't inherently have a width or a height. Do you mean Object? Illustrator has a Document Info Panel.

Comment: Exactly. eg Cyan channel of objects in document.

Comment: Exactly. For Photoshop it's available at this link.
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6886/how-to-get-layer-size-width-and-height
Can it be done Similar in Illustrator? Or how?

Comment: I'm curious ... what will you use this for?

Comment: @Wolff OP wants to measure size of plate needed.

Comment: @joojaa, yeah I understand, but when is this useful to know?

Comment: @Wolff i would say that when you, cut the stock to etch copper plates?

Comment: @joojaa, interesting. Do they really use different sized plates or each ink? In offset it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Wolff i wouldnt, but some machines have no problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok better approach. Works only for CMYK documents for obvious reasons. Also since illustrator is based on objects wont do anything for raster/gradient/mesh elements

1. Copy your arwork to safety!
2. Do **Edit → Color -> Adjust Color Balance**

   - set Magenta, Yellow and black to -100
3. Do a merge
4. Delete white
5. Select everything and read values form the transform panel

[image]

**Image 1**: Step by step, original image [Abstract vector created by macrovector - www.freepik.com](https://www.freepik.com/vectors/abstract), cleaned colors a bit for enough channel clarity.

Can be recorded into a keyboard shortcut with the actions panel:

[image]

But really juts copy to photoshop?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115896/discussion-on-answer-by-joojaa-how-can-any-color-width-and-height-be-found-in-il).